# Creating a Docker Container to deploy to a prod env

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I'm having some problems with building my application through Jenkins and running the container on a extrernal tomcat.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.16.3
RUN ls -al
WORKDIR /app
COPY /package/repo/package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY /package/repo /app
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start]
```

npm start calls `node server.js`

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`);
  console.log(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html');

});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

`docker build -t reacttest .`
`docker run reacttest`

I'm trying to access the container using localhost:8080, however, whenever I access that port, I'm getting error not found. Is there a step I'm missing. Sorry, i'm very new to docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map a port from your machine to the container. Use the p flag for this.

```sh
docker run reacttest -p 8080:8080
```

In general the syntax is:

```sh
docker run <image> -p <host port>:<container port>
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Comment: Thanks so much, I was doing docker run <image> -p <host port>, didnt know about container port

Answer (score 0):

`EXPOSE` does not accually publish the port. You should run you container with `-p` flag to map ports from container to your host system. See the [documents](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).